# error occur while uploading excel size about 2.5mb in form page

Tags: php, out-of-memory, excellibrary

I'm reading the excel file in php using excel library. Its showing error after uploading.

Error like

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 8388608 bytes)

How can I solve this issue.

Comment: Change the memory limit ini_set('memory_limit', '-1') or edit your php.ini file. Edit memory_limit to your desire value.

Comment: As You wish. Something is consuming Your memory - we are not fairies - we don't know what is in Your system. Probably You've got memory leaks somewhere. Show us suspected code, maybe we will find something.

Comment: You can also break down your file into small files and upload them.

Comment: After changing memory_limit value in php.ini it will work. Thanks for all